# Correct description/numbering of formulas across multiple pages

Tags: article-writing

I don't want to discuss a mathematical problem here, I want to ask how to meaningfully present formulas that extend over several pages.
Attached is my suggestion where on the first page the equation was numbered. Since it should be clear to the reader that something is still missing here, I have not included any further information (to be continued).
On the next page I numbered the continued formula again with the note "cont.".

How did you handle this with long formulas?[image]

Comment: Whatever you choose to do, the publisher will do something different.

Comment: It's for my thesis. I would be interested in the different possible variants.

Comment: If it's for your thesis, ask your thesis supervisor. (She'll make you change it, anyway.)